# Place of middleware in express js really matters?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use a middleware for my application so as a POC I just made a simple middleware for my application with the following code.

```
var processingPage = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Req.Query "+req.url);
    next();
}

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(processingPage);
```

At this stage the processingPage midlleware dint work when request comes,So I changed the code like below(Moved  `app.use(processingPage);` to top)

```
var processingPage = function(req, res, next) {     
    console.log("Req.Query "+req.url);
    next();
}

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(processingPage);
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

after this the middleware starts to work . Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Because middleware is processed in order in which it is declared (Express doesn't have a way to declare middleware dependencies or priorities, so it needs to infer the order in which the middleware is executed by when it is `app.use()`'d).

By moving your middleware to the end of the chain, the chance that another middleware sends back a response (and ending the middleware chain) is quite large.

My guess is that the request you're testing with is being handled by `app.router` or `express.static`.

This also means that `allowCrossDomain` should be moved upwards in the middleware chain, due to the same reason.